# What happens with views when we scroll big layout in android - view lifecycle

Tags: android, android-layout, ondraw

I'd like to understand what happens with views when we scrolls big layouts with lots of views, let's say what is lifecycle of view looks like in such case.

On developer site ([link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)) I reed:

> Drawing begins with the root node of the layout. It is requested to
>   measure and draw the layout tree. Drawing is handled by walking the
>   tree and rendering each View that intersects the invalid region.

and

> The framework will not draw View objects that are not in the invalid
>   region, and also will take care of drawing the View background for
>   you.

so on the begging all views are constructed but android draws only these one which are visible.  What happens when the view is not in invalid region anymore? It wouldn't be just invalidated and redrawn or something else happens? GC comes to play?

What happens when view is not in invalid region on the beginning, is it initially drawn or it waits for invalid region to be drawn first time?

The next question is connected with invalidating view and scrolling. I know that the view is invalidated when some change is made, like change background of view or change text of textview, but what happens when the user scrolls our layout, all of visible views are invalidated and redraw 60 times per seconds?

I would be happy if someone could put some light on the mechanisms which are working under the hood.